# Day # Column in R

Tags: r, date

I am interested in adding an additional column onto a dataset I have in R. It would be the Day # that an observation was recorded for. The days may not necessarily be consecutive and some days may repeat and some may not. A desired output is shown below:

```
Day          Date
  1    2017-01-02
  1    2017-01-02
  2    2017-01-04
  2    2017-01-04
  3    2017-01-07
  4    2017-01-10
```

I need it to be something robust that I could apply to many different datasets and still produce the desired output.

Comment: Just do `df1$Day <- cumsum(!duplicated(df1$Date))`

Comment: Thank you!! This works perfectly.